# Как создать страницу с помощью Thymeleaf с header - content - footer на разных страницах

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Для избежания копирования ненужного кода хочу разделить страницу на 3 части, header, content и footer. Раньше я пользовался jsp и просто вставлял с помощью `<%@ include file = "header.jsp"%>` Сейчас хочу освоить Thymeleaf и хотелось бы сделать что-то подобное. И как это использовать в разрезе Spring. Ранее я делал контроллер на подобии:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome() {

    model.addAttribute("Hello", "Hello world");

    return "welcome";
}
```

Можно оставить так, или же для Thymeleaf нужно по другому как-то? Я читал о фрагментах, но не понял, как это связать с контроллером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В контроллере ничего не меняется. Просто создаёте три файла

**header.html**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <body>
    <div th:fragment="content">
      Верхняя часть страницы
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**footer.html**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <body>
    <div th:fragment="content">
      Нижняя часть страницы
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**welcome.html**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Привет!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div th:replace="header :: content"></div>
    <div>
      Основная часть страницы
    </div>
    <div th:replace="footer :: content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

и всё. У Thymeleaf очень [простая и подробная документация](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout).